# How to create a nested dictionary from two dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Imagine you have two dictionaries:

```
a = {'x': 1}
b = {'y': 2}
```

How can I get a dictionary like:

```
 {
   'a' : {'x': 1},
   'b' : {'y': 2}
 }
```

?

Comment: Your output data structure is not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace your equal signs with colons:

```
d = {
   'a' : {'x': 1},
   'b' : {'y': 2}
}
```

If you had a list of individual dictionaries, you can convert it to a dictionary of dictionaries with a dictionary comprehension as you iterate through the list:

```
list_of_dicts =[{'x': 1}, {'y': 2}, {'z': 3}]
dict_of_dicts  ={idx:dic for idx, dic in enumerate(list_of_dicts)}

#{0: {'x': 1}, 1: {'y': 2}, 2: {'z': 3}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
new_dict = {
    'a': a,
    'b': b,
}
```